# Postfix cannot authenticate against SASL

Tags: mysql, postfix, debian-wheezy, sasl

My system is Debian 7 aka Wheezy with postfix, courier, and mysql installed. Courier works well and if I issue

```
testsaslauthd -u user@domain -p password -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux -s smtp
```

I get a

```
0: OK "Success."
```

However, if I get a base64 encoded username/password with

```
echo -ne '\000user@domain\000password' | openssl base64
```

and try to use that in a SMTP session using

```
helo localhost
auth plain (output from above)
```

I always get a

```
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
```

In `/var/log/syslog` I find then

```
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: warning: localhost[::1]: SASL plain authentication failed: authentication failure
```

and in /var/log/auth.log

```
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin Parse the username username@domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin trying to open db 'postfixadmin' on host '127.0.0.1'
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: begin transaction
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin create statement from userPassword username domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin doing query SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username="username@domain";
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: commit transaction
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin Parse the username username@domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin trying to open db 'postfixadmin' on host '127.0.0.1'
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin Parse the username username@domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin trying to open db 'postfixadmin' on host '127.0.0.1'
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: begin transaction
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin create statement from userPassword username domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin doing query SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username="username@domain";
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin create statement from cmusaslsecretPLAIN username domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin doing query SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username="username@domain";
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: commit transaction
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin Parse the username username@domain
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Sep 29 21:49:34 (hostname obfuscated) postfix/smtpd[15814]: sql plugin trying to open db 'postfixadmin' on host '127.0.0.1'
```

Relevant SASL entries in my postfix configuration:

```
# postconf | grep -e cyrus_sasl -e smtpd_sasl
cyrus_sasl_config_path =
send_cyrus_sasl_authzid = no
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks =
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to analyse or debug this?

**Update 2014/10/01:** After trying around more and more, I found out that it is definitely a problem with reading the password from the mysql database. I edited `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` and in the last line I wrote

```
sql_select: SELECT 'some hard coded password' password FROM mailbox WHERE username="%u@%r"
```

and now it works. However, this is obviously *not* what I intended to do.

**Second Update 2014/10/01:** Interesting... When smtpd.conf just contains

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

everything works as it should! Solved for me.

Comment: command `echo -ne '\000user@domain\000password' | openssl base64` was one method to test auth via telnet. Did you try other option described in http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_test ?

Comment: @masegaloeh: Which other option? Connecting via openssl? Yes, I tried that, the result is exactly the same.

Comment: I mean to method to format your username & password to AUTH format, for example `perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("\0username\0password");'`

Comment: @masegaloeh: Okay, now I know what you mean. Yes, I tried that too, the result was the same as with bash's echo.

Comment: Congratulations, You should post the solution to the answer section, so this question doesn't float in *unanswered* pool :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` only has to contain

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to change

```
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
```

to

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

and make sure dovecot-imapd is installed.